# Rails form not saving to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, haml, form-for

I've been trying to get this form working for ages now and I can't seem to get it working. The most annoying part is that everything appears to be working properly, but nothing shows up in the database.

Controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save!
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Lesson was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Model

```
attr_accessible  :userID, :groupID, :postTime, :postText
```

View add post

```
#uploadStyle
    = form_for Post.new do |f|
      = f.label :postText, 'PostText'
      = f.text_area :postText
      %br
      = f.label :postTime, 'PostTime'
      = f.text_area :postTime
      %br
      = f.label :userID, 'UserID'
      = f.text_area :userID
      %br
      = f.label :groupID, 'GroupID'
      = f.text_area :groupID
      %br
      = submit_tag 'Submit'
```

Logs

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-10 22:04:32 -0700
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AUq6mt54N7kA67M1L9wQdqhl2UPRxhOEZOv/LSowcJU=", "post"=>{"postText"=>"work please", "postTime"=>"2013-01-01 04:24:23", "userID"=>"1", "groupID"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
Rendered posts/index.html.haml within layouts/application (12.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 24.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Routes

```
  root :to  => 'posts#index'
  match '/posts', :to => 'posts#index'

  resources :posts do
    member do
      post 'upload'
    end
  end

  match '/posts/:id', :to => 'posts#show', :format => false
  match '/add_post', :to => 'posts#add_post'
```

Comment: can you add your routes to the question? They seem odd - it isn't even getting to your `create` action. 'Processing by PostsController#index' Nor is it behaving as if it did - your code says you would either see the form again, or go to the Post page, and you're getting neither of those results.

Comment: do you have any constraints on any of the post model attributes?  the save! method won't save anything to the database if there's a validation issue.  Try creating a record manually using the rails console (type rails c from your project root from a command prompt/terminal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your routing - you've got a lot of contradictory things going on there.

Resourceful routing is the preferred way of doing routing in Rails - thats the `resources :posts` part. If you use just that, you get routes for index, new, create, show, edit, update, and delete - some of those overlap with what you have for `match /posts`, `match /posts/:id`, and `match /add_post`.

If you remove those, your code should work as expected and submitting the form will be processed by the `create` action of your controller.

More information on routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

*edit*: You can also see all the routes in your system by running `rake routes` in the command line. In the output of that, you'll see that `POST /posts` matches the index action of your PostsController, which is what you are seeing, when it should match the `create` action.

Comment: feel free to accept the answer if it has solved the problem :)